# Access fields of an object passed as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, object, parameter-passing, field

Is it possible, in Java, to access fields of an object that is passed as a parameter in a method?

Example code:

```
void myMethod(ArrayList<Integer> list, MyClass object) {   
        Integer myInt = object.x; // x is an Integer-type field in the object
}
```

I tried the following:
`MyClass curObj = (MyClass)object;` to no avail.

Any suggestions?

When I use `javac` to compile, I get a `cannot find symbol` error.

Comment: When debugging, check the `object` object to see first if it's null.

Comment: This should work - provided MyClass.x has the right visibility (try public).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly why simply not access object directly? e.g. if object had a member `memberName` and `methodName()` method, which are public, you could simply do

```
void myMethod(ArrayList<Integer> list, MyClass object) {   
    object.memberName = "member Name"
    object.methodName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cast your 'object' as it is only object in name, you are getting passed a MyClass Object.

And by that I mean you are getting `MyClass object` not `Object object`

To access x like that make it sure it is public, BUT you should make an accessor method in MyClass:

```
public Integer getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

and change your line to:

```
Integer myInt = object.getX();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Of course

Your example code should work as is.
See that the field x has the word `public` in your MyClass.

```
//In MyClass
public Integer x;
```

If you don't declare it public you have to provide a getter method. This is the normal case (private + getter) JAVA Bean...

```
//In MyClass
private Integer x;
public Integer getX()
{
  return x;
}

void myMethod(ArrayList<Integer> list, MyClass object) {   
    Integer myInt = object.getX(); // x is an Integer-type field in the object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No reasons it shouldn't work unless

- `object` is null (but this would be a run-time, not compile-time error)
- `x` is not public and `myMethod` is not a method of the `MyClass` class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if your attribute is declared as public. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int test;
}

class Test {
    public printMyClass( MyClass c ) {
        System.out.println( c.test );
    }
}
```

Or you can have one method that returns test value and only MyClass can modify test attribute (better).

```
public class MyClass {
    private int test;
    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}

class Test {
    public printMyClass( MyClass c ) {
        System.out.println( c.getTest() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if `MyClass.x` is a public, then yes. Otherwise, you can reach it via that property's getter/setter methods. Java is actually passing a copy of the reference to the object, so while the called method is working only with the reference copy, the underlying object is the same whether you access it via a reference or a copy of the reference. The state of the object is also exposed for potential changes from within the called method.